# VS 2019 install hangs when installing ASP.Net 4.5

Tags: visual-studio-2019, asp.net-4.5

I am installing VS2019 Enterprise on a new Windows 11 laptop but it gets about 60% through the installation process and then hangs while trying to install ASP.Net4.5. I have seen other posts which report a similar problem with VS2017 and the solution given is to kill a process called DISM but this is not running on my laptop.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks